# Passing an object into a class by reference

Tags: c++, oop, parameters

Right Ill try to explain my thinking here. 
I have two classes at the moment, known as class1 and class2.
I want to pass an object of class2 into an object of class1, by reference.

but i want to only have to pass it in once, rather than having to pass it in every time a method is called.

I've tried creating a pointer and I have tried creating a reference, but to no avail. 
Any help appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myclass
{
    private:
int i;

    public:
myclass()
{
}
void method()
{
    cout << "Enter num: ";
    cin >> i;
}
void display()
{
    cout << i;
}
};

class relatedclass
{

    public:

relatedclass(myclass ob)
{
    pmc = &ob;
}
myclass *pmc;

};

void main()
{
myclass mc;

relatedclass rc(mc);

//display value of mc.i
mc.display();
cout << endl;

//ok lets change the i variable
rc.pmc->method();
cout << endl;

//display new value of mc.i
mc.display();
cout << endl;
}
```

for the test date I entered 50, and i expected the mc object to be updated and i would now equal 50.

Comment: Can you show us what you actually tried?

Comment: At what time do you want an object of class2 to be passed "into" an object of class1?

Comment: Are class1 and class2 related in any way?

Comment: IIRC, all objects are passed by reference, you're never storing the actual object, you're storing a reference to that object.

Comment: @Truth: That might be true for Java or C#, but it's not for C++. In the code example the `relatedclass` constructor creates a copy of the `myclass` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct class2 {
  int i, j;
};
struct class1 {
  class2& c2;
  class1(class2& c2) : c2(c2) {}
  void Froz() {
    c2.i = c2.j;
  }
  int Baz() {
    return c2.i * c2.j;
  }
};
```

---

**EDIT**: In your example, in the `relatedclass` constructor, you take the address of a local variable. That variable will be destroyed when the constructor returns. After that, your `pmc` pointer points to a destroyed object, which is a no-no.

Change this line:

```
relatedclass(myclass ob)
```

to this

```
relatedclass(myclass& ob)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!, Can't believe I forgot that. So I understand this solution the pmc pointer wont point to a destroyed object?

Comment: It will point to the object you actually pass in, instead of pointing to a local copy that will be immediately destroyed. Specifically, `pmc` will point to `mc`; `*pmc` will remain valid for precisely as long as `mc` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold a member variable of class2 in class1 like this and have a set variable set the member variable.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class class2 
{
public:
    int m_i;
};

class class1 
{
public:
    void set(class2& c2) { m_c2 = c2; };
    class2 m_c2;
};

void main()
{
    class2 c2;
    c2.m_i = 2;

    class1 c1;
    c1.set(c2);

    cout << c1.m_c2.m_i << std::endl;

}
```